# htaccess rewrite url match subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to modify my website URL for better SEO. Here's what i have so far:

```
 RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

i want `http://www.domain.com/page-10`
instead of `http://www.domain.com/index.php?p=10`

but how do i also match `http://www.domain.com/category/index.php?p=2`
and rewrite it to `http://www.domain.com/category/page-2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can another rule for `/category/`:

```
RewriteRule ^(category)/page-(\d+)/?$ $1/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^page-(\d+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

You even **combine both rules** into one with this regex.

```
RewriteRule ^(category/)?page-(\d+)/?$ $1index.php?p=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: "category" was just an example, it can be another string (i have 50 categories)

Comment: You can then use: `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/page-(\d+)/?$ $1/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` as first rule.

Comment: I'm having a problem with a URL like this http://mysubdomain.domain.com/category/page-2

Comment: the above example points to /public_html/mysubdomain/index.php while it should be pointing to /public_html/category/index.php .. any way to fix that ? I have multiple subdomains so the index.php?p= can be requested through many subdomains or none at all

Comment: Is there any rule/config that is already adding `subdomain/` to ` mysubdomain.domain.com` URLs?

Comment: well in my folder structures the subdomains are physical folders inside my root so the root of a subdomain is /public_html/mysubdomain/

Comment: I think we cannot resolve this subdomain situation using comment. Please open a new question linking this one and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`http://www.domain.com/category/index.php?p=2` to 
`http://www.domain.com/category/index.php?p=page-2` 
and re-write your htaccess to match:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)-([a-z]+)  http://www.domain.com/category/index.php?p=$1-$2 [NC]
```